# Rsync: backup Windows to Linux (remote)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rsync

I have a Linux computer (Ubuntu Server) connected to the net which have rsync installed.

And, I would like to backup a Windows machine (Windows 10) to it, using rsync with a security layer. I heard about rsync through ssh, and then I am asking how may I do that backup, from the Windows machine to the Linux computer.

I would not like to install a new program in the Linux server. What program would you suggest for the Windows side? My Windows machine has ssh and robocopy, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup of Windows operating system to a Linux server via rsync through ssh, is not that straightforward/simple. For instance you need to define

- scope of the backup

  - what files, folders are needed.
  - give necessary permissions to the user which is going to perform the backup
- how such a backup is restored

  - test the restore procedure

You also need to be aware that [Windows file permissions won't be carried over](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547275/how-do-i-use-rsync-to-reliably-transfer-permissions-acls-when-copying-from-ntf) by rsync

A good walkthrough is available [here](https://ls-a.org/2019/05/30/centralized-backups-using-rsync-and-openssh-on-windows-10/) - but the point is you will have to put in place your own solution.

You can also consider offering an SMB share on the Linux server and using the integrated Windows backup software to backup your files there.

Comment: i suggests that you install veeam agent and use a smb share

Comment: SMB is dangerous, no?